# Connecting the google assistant to my MariaDB on my NAS

Tags: mariadb, actions-on-google

I am trying to connect my google assistant to my MariaDB database that's running on my NAS. I'm building ESP8266 controlled smarthome lamps. I discoverd the actions on google, but I found it quite complicated. I have already a way that it works, but i'm not a fan of it. I made it work with IFTTT and AdafuitIO. But at adafruit you need to pay for more switches and stuff. What i really want is to make ik with google assistent that connects directly to my database. I found that's a local thing with google assistant is called 'local home SDK'.

Summarized.
I am looking for an local only solution to connect my google assistant to my MariaDb database, it needs to put a 0 or 1 to the right column.

It would be great if someone can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Actions on Google expects a publicly accessible URL to send requests. [Local Fulfillment](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/local) works for execution but still needs a URL for other types of events.

You may need to create some sort of adapter on your local network which exposes or accesses a public URL and synchronizes it with your local network database.